# Pdf security with flash script, possible?

Tags: flash, security, pdf

My friend asked whether it's possible to set time limits on pdf files, so a pdf can't be opened after a date. I searched and found some software that can make this but they cost $$$$. As far as i know swf can be embedded into pdf.(i am .net programmer so i am not a flash, pdf expert) I wonder if this can be done: Create an actionscript(and embed it into a pdf), which kills acrobat reader when opening the pdf after a date. Also any other ideas are welcome. Thanks for reading and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such security is worthless as it's removed and bypassed easily. Just change time on your computer.